# An Beginner Immigrant from C sharp to Vb simple issue

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

```
Public Function ExecCommand(ByVal sql As String) As SqlDataReader
    Dim dReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = sql
    cmd.Connection = sm
    Dim isOpened = OpenConnection()
    If isOpened Then
      dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
      CloseConnection()
    End If
    Return dReader
End Function
```

It says maybe a null refrence may occur at runtime for the declaring of that datareader. Why is that?

Comment: What is your function supposed to return if `isOpened` is false?

Comment: I often want to weep when I see some of the code posted on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the `dReader` variable might not be initialized if the If condition is not satisfied. You could initialize it to `Nothing` by default:

```
Dim dReader As SqlDataReader = Nothing
```

Obviously the caller of this method need to handle this case.

Also as a C# immigrant you are probably surprised why you are not getting a compile time error but only a warning.

Answer (score 2):

if OpenConnection() fails, then isOpened is false. The following block will not get executed and dReader will not have been assigned.

```
Public Function ExecCommand(ByVal sql As String) As SqlDataReader
    Dim dReader As SqlDataReader       // Not assigned yet
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = sql
    cmd.Connection = sm
    Dim isOpened = OpenConnection()    // Fails to connect
    If isOpened Then                   // Not executed
      dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
      CloseConnection()
    End If
    Return dReader                     // Return value unknown
```

As a sidenote, CloseConnection() is not executed either so you might have some problems later.

Answer (score 0):

add else statemnt in which assign dreader as null.

```
Public Function ExecCommand(ByVal sql As String) As SqlDataReader 
Dim dReader As SqlDataReader=Nothing
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
 cmd.CommandText = sql  


cmd.Connection = sm
```

Dim isOpened = OpenConnection()
     If isOpened Then 
      dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader() 
      CloseConnection()
 End If
 Return dReader End Function